# Why only one date is transferred from view to controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I have a simple form for bill creating. I have two date fields on this form.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
```

On view I have two fields (datepickers):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">From date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control date-pickerFrom", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">To date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control date-pickerTo", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." })
    </div>
</div>
```

At the end of the view I have JavaScript functions for that two datepickers:

```
$(function () {
    $('.date-pickerFrom').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
    $('.date-pickerTo').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
});
```

When I confirm my form I only get the right date value in controller for "From date" field. "To date" value is always 01/01/0001. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: How do you receive those fields? Seems you have empty ToDate field (probably you're getting it from DB and it's null there).

Comment: How you post these dates to controller via form submit or ajax call. Could you please show that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your View to:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">From date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FromDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "datepickerFrom", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..."}})
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">To date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ToDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "datepickerTo", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..."}})
    </div>
</div>
```

And call them in your JavaScript as:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datepickerFrom').datepicker({
               dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
            });

            $('#datepickerTo').datepicker({
               dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
           });
       });
```

Assign a `id` to each datepicker and it should work for you.

Comment: There is a JavaScript error in your console. This happens with multiple date picker on the same page. The above answer should solve your problems. If yes, mark it as answer

Comment: What about edit that entity (bill)? I tried with `var $datepicker = $('#datepickerFrom'); $datepicker.datepicker(); $datepicker.datepicker("setDate", "@Model.FromDate.ToShortDateString()");` and `$('#datepickerFrom').datepicker("setDate", "10/12/2012");` but doesnt work for me...

Comment: @vkel Try setting your `Model` value in your Jquery like this: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.FromDate.ToShortDateString()));` or you can set the default value in your `@Html` helper syntax.

Comment: So you mean like that: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FromDate,... … , @value = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.FromDate.ToShortDateString())) } })`? I already tried this and did not help. In html the value is ok (value="4/1/2019"). But I get error: $(...).datepicker is not a function. I check that and I have only one yquery included..

Comment: @vkel No, if you want to set something that you got from your controller in your JQuery, then use what I menitoned in my comment. For you case, if you want to set a default value to your date, you can set it like this: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ToDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "datepickerTo", @class = "form-control", @Value = @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),@placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..."}})`. This will set a default value to your textbox with the current date.

Comment: It is not important which value I want to set, the problem is that doesnt work. If I check HTML of page, I can see value="4/1/2019" but on the website GUI - textbox, I have only dd. mm. llll. Its look like that value is ok, but datapicker doesnt show that.

Comment: @vkel What do you mean by doesn't work? If you want to set the default date in the datepicker, refer to the `defaultDate` option: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate. Remove the `@Value` field from your `@EditorFor` and specify your date in the Jquery.

Comment: @RahulSharma Thank you for your help but that doesnt work. I will try something else.